Not able to process large data with TRPC in nextjs
I have a excel with around 500 rows, which are being read correctly and I am trying to push all the rows data to mongodb via TRPC call.
But getting below error.
net::ERR_CONNECTION_RESET 431 (Request Header Fields Too Large)

<Input
                id="fileInput"
                className="hidden"
                type="file"
                onChange={async (e) => {
                  console.log('file found: ' + e.target.files![0]);
                  const file = e.target.files![0];
                  if(!file){
                    toast.error('No file found');
                    return;
                  }
                  const data = await file.arrayBuffer();
                  const workbook = XLSX.read(data);
                  var sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;

                  sheet_name_list.forEach(function (y) {
                    
                    var roa = XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[y]!);
                    console.log('all the rows');
                    console.log(roa);
                    roa.forEach((row: any) => {
                      
                        mutation.mutate({
                          basePrice: row['BasePrice'],
                          gstRate: row['GstRate'],
                          totalPrice: row['TotalPrice'],
                          commissionValue: row['CommissionValue'],
                          productCategory: ProductCategory.CLASSICTSHIRT,
                          classicTshirtSize: row['ClassicTshirtSize'],
                          classicTshirtColor: row['ClassicTshirtColor'],
                          classicTshirtFront: row['ClassicTshirtFront']=='Y',
                        });
                    });
                  });
                  toast.success('Data is processed');
                }}
              />

Below is the code for my mutation variable.
const mutation = trpc.product.bulkUpdateMasterPrice.useMutation({
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log('data is processed');
    },
    onError: (error) => {
      // toast.error('Something went wrong. Please try again.');
      console.error(error);
    },
  });


Issue is resolved, there was some issue with my excel data, which was not mapped correctly.
